# how to include my asp.net website under sharepoint?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, application-integration

I i have the asp.net web site with c# + sql server 2008 connectivity + css + javascripts + ajax . I have a solution. i want to run this site under sharepoint . What i have to do for integrate this ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to create an sub-directory that acts as a `buffer` to block/remove the inherited items from the .net 2 / 3.5 framework and then create your application under this.

Assuming you name the `buffer` application `apps`, and your custom .NET 4.0 application is called `myapp`, your resulting application would reside at:

http://[sharepoint-site]/apps/myapp/

How to do this:

1. Create a sub-directory `apps` under the root of your SharePoint
   site
2. Go into security for the `apps` directory and add `everyone` with Read permissions
3. In IIS, convert this to an application and pick the same app-pool
   that your SharePoint site is  running under
4. Create a web.config under `/apps/`, this will block/remove the
   SharePoint stuff (see below for the code block)
5. Create your `myapp` directory under `apps` (ex. /apps/myapp/)
6. In IIS, go into Application Pools, create a new AppPool, `MyApp .NET v4.0`
7. Go into `Advanced Settings` > `Identity` and add the same AD domain user account
   credentials that your SharePoint site is using
8. Still in IIS, go back to `myapp` and convert to an application and pick the `MyApp .NET v4.0` AppPool
9. Copy your code over and you're done!

The web.config file in the `apps` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <clear/>
    </httpModules>
    <webParts>
      <transformers>
        <clear />
      </transformers>
    </webParts>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="OwssvrHandler" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="svc-Integrated" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
      <remove name="ScriptResource" />
      <remove name="JSONHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="ReportViewerWebPart" />
      <remove name="ReportViewerWebControl" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <!-- depending on any customizations, you may have to add/remove items from this list as needed -->
      <remove name="SPRequestModule" />
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <remove name="SharePoint14Module" />
      <remove name="StateServiceModule" />
      <remove name="PublishingHttpModule" />
      <remove name="RSRedirectModule" />
    </modules>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. The first is a simple IFrame webpart that hosts the entire application in a frame. The page viewer webpart is built into sharepoint, and does this for you.

The second is using Application Pages. I have not done this, but here is an MSDN article on them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732.aspx

The third is to embed the controls of you app into Webparts, and then place these into web part zones on sharepoint pages.

The approach you take depends on the size of your app and the time you have to integrate it. The IFrame Approach is quick and dirty, while the webpart approach is much more native, but can take a long time for large apps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any luck trying to get another site to co-exist with SharePoint. Is it not possible for you to create this site of yours in its own web site, with its own app pool, and then just link to it from SharePoint?