# How to realize cross-domain security with iFrame custom website under the sharepoint website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, sharepoint, iframe

How to realize cross-domain security with `iFrame` custom website under the **SharePoint** website

The requirements are following:

1. User is going be authenticated under **SharePoint**
2. Custom application is ASP .NET MVC 4
3. The custom application should *reject* any request that comes outside of the "mother/host" application and make sure that user is *authenticated*.

I don't have any experience with **SharePoint** and I have no clue how it can be done.

Thanks in advance, folk!

P.S. I found some links but it doesn't help about what the approach I have to use...
http://thinketg.com/iframes-in-sharepoint-2013/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028(VS.85).aspx
[how to include my asp.net website under sharepoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648419/how-to-include-my-asp-net-website-under-sharepoint)

Comment: Same situation here. If you have the answer, please share it ;). I'll be around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are no good news on that. 
Here is the best I could find:

> You can't use the advantage of SPContext. You can't even use the
>   server object model because your application is in .net 4.0. For
>   exemple, creating a new SPSite won't work.
>
> Only solutions :
>
> 1. Call SharePoint WebServices from your ASP.NET MVC app Create
> 2. WebServices hosted in SharePoint. (and call them from your app)

source: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/integrating-asp-net-mvc-3-and-sharepoint