# I need to include my simple MVC asp.net website under SharePoint?

Tags: asp.net, iis, sharepoint, admin

how to include asp.net website under SharePoint.
i don't want to use any iframe or webpart.
the approach i am  trying is add virtual directory into iis site and then apply option **convert into application**.

Please help me out i am very new in this field.

Comment: even i have tried this option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648419/how-to-include-my-asp-net-website-under-sharepoint but not able to understand what exactly i need to do

Comment: yoo i am able to run site inside sharepoint iis site :)